# How does the FindShortestPath function handle situations with multiple paths and how does this affect the BetweennessCentrality function?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm using the `FindShortestPath` function and am curious to know how Mathematica determines the shortest path when multiple such paths exist.

Here's what I have:

```
A = {{0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}
G = AdjacencyGraph[A, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
FindShortestPath[G, 1, 4]
```

The output is `{1,2,4}`. However, `{1,3,4}` is also valid. How does Mathematica choose? According to the order of the entries, 1,2,3,4?

Also, how is `BetweennessCentrality` handled in such cases? For example,

```
BetweennessCentrality[G]
```

yields `{0,.5,.5,0}`. The zeros are obvious. However, (2) falls one of the two shortest paths from (1) to (4). Do we count it as contributing 1/2 to the `BetweennessCentrality` of (2), or is there a normalization constant I'm missing?

Comment: As for betweenness, reading up on the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality#Definition) will answer the question. As for the shortest path, do not assume that there is any connection between the implementations of `BetweennessCentrality` and `FindShortestPath`.   Also, it is not safe to make any assumptions about which path is returned—what if the implementation changes in the next version?

Comment: To understand how the decision *might* be made, I suggest you look at the usual algorithms for finding shortest paths. For the unweighted case, it can be done with a breadth first search. Think about how you'd implement a BFS, and how various implementation choices may impact which path is found. This should clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

Re the second part of the question:

[BetweennessCentrality  >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BetweennessCentrality.html):

> - *BetweennessCentrality for a vertex $i$ in a connected graph is given by $\sum _ {s,t\in v\land s \neq i\land t \neq i}\frac{n_
>      {s,t}^i}{n_{s,t}}$, where $n_{s,t}$ is the number of shortest paths
>     from $s$ to $t$ and $n_ {s,t}^i$ is the number of shortest paths from
>     $s$ to $t$ passing through $ i$.*

To find all paths between vertices `1` and `4` you can use [`FindPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPath.html):

```
FindPath[G, 1, 4, {GraphDistance[G, 1, 4]}, All]
```

> {{1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4}}

Re: *How does Mathematica choose? According to the order of the entries, 1,2,3,4?*

Your guess that the path among multiple shortest paths is selected based on `VertexIndex`es  is supported by the following small experiment:

```
G2 = AdjacencyGraph[{a, c, b, d},A, VertexLabels -> "Name"] 
FindShortestPath[G2, a, d]
```

> {a, c, d}

```
G3 = AdjacencyGraph[{a, z, w, d},A, VertexLabels -> "Name"] 
FindShortestPath[G3, a, d]
```

> {a, z, d}